# Qt C++ - Delete row in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory-management

I'm new to Qt and I want to do this

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() + 1);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString("1")));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,1, new QTableWidgetItem(QString("1")));
    }

    QPushButton *listB = new QPushButton[5];
    QHBoxLayout *listLayout = new QHBoxLayout[5];
    QWidget* listWidget = new QWidget[5];

    for (int i = 0 ; i <  5 ; ++i)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() + 1);
        listB[i].setText("OK");
        listLayout[i].addWidget(listB + i);
        listWidget[i].setLayout(listLayout + i);
        ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,0,listWidget + i);
        connect(listB + i , &QPushButton::clicked, [=]{ui->tableWidget->removeRow(i);});
    }

}
```

I want to add a QPushButton in each row of QTableWidget and when i click to this Button, the corresponding row will disappear. However whenever i click to Button it cause "Segmentation Error".

Please point out what wrong with my code and what is the solution for my program.
Thanks.

Comment: The slot connected to the button calls `removeRow(i)`, where `i=0...4`. However, after one row is removed, e.g. `i=0`, then row 4 will be invalid (index out of range), and may causing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the arrays it has generated, it seems that deleting an element from the array causes problems with the index.

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() + 1);
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString("1")));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,1, new QTableWidgetItem(QString("1")));
    }


    for (int i = 0 ; i <  5 ; ++i)
    {
        QPushButton *listB = new QPushButton;
        QHBoxLayout *listLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        QWidget* listWidget = new QWidget;
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() + 1);
        listB->setText("OK");
        listLayout->addWidget(listB);
        listWidget->setLayout(listLayout);
        ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,0,listWidget);
        connect(listB, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]{ui->tableWidget->removeRow(i);});
    }

}
```